# Entity framework 6 - Some objects of the list returned by context have an empty property

Tags: c#, entity-framework, dbcontext, ef-fluent-api

I am retrieving a list of entities like this :

```
var traductions = from t in context.Traductions
                        where t.User.ID == user.ID
                        && (DateTime.Now < t.EndDate)
                        select t;

var list = traductions.ToList();
```

Here is the model :

```
Here is the first class :

    public class Original
    {
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; private set; }
    public Traduction Traduction { get; private set; }
    }
```

And here is the second class :

```
   public class Traduction
   { 
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public Original Original { get; private set; }
    public string Content { get; private set; }
   }
```

I get 4 entities - that's good - however one of the properties of some of my retrieved objects is null - Original. In 3 of the 4 object the Original property is null, but this property is correctly populated in the 4th. I have checked in the Database directly and the Primary Keys / FK are consistent.

What do you think about it? I don't understand because normally if there is a problem this property should be null for all the retrieved objects, but here the property is correctly populated for one of the objects.

Thanks

Comment: Well I have added the models, I hate the down-voting function of SO with those people who down vote without even pointing where the problem is.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @CarlosMuñoz Here the main problem is that this a working code that to me is not supposed to produce any error. Therefore I can't be more specific without knowing the answer of my question.

Comment: That's why I was asking for suggestions about what to check, how to handle the problem, so people could also tell me if anything should be added in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My first thought is you might have a circular reference.  Is it possible to have a Traduction, that contains an Original that contains the first Traduction?  If you do that could be what you're seeing.  You'll definitely have problems if/when you try to serialize things.

The following won't help a circular reference, but could be why the data is not loading as you'd expect.

You could try using lazy loading.  To do that you'll use the 'virtual' keyword in your classes like:

```
public class Original
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; private set; }
    public virtual Traduction Traduction { get; private set; }
}

public class Traduction
{ 
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public virtual Original Original { get; private set; }
    public string Content { get; private set; }
}
```

Or you can specifically include the objects in your query:

```
var traductions = from t in context.Traductions.Include("Original")
                  where t.User.ID == user.ID
                  && (DateTime.Now < t.EndDate)
                  select t;
```

Comment: Sir.. you are awesome !!!!! Lazy Loading solved it. So it means that every time I create a one-to-one relationship with a reference on both side I create circular references ? Is it a bad practice ?

Comment: A circular relationship isn't automatically bad, but does require special handling.  Maybe you could shed some light on what you're design is trying to accomplish so I understand what you're doing better.